# sharecad.org cadframe viewer not showing .dxf file

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, autocad, dxf

I'm working on some CAD file in .Net MVC where I use to generate .DXF file and trying to view it using an iframe provided by sharecad.org
Here is the frame I used

```
<iframe src="https://sharecad.org/cadframe/load?url=https://xyz/data/Demo.dxf" scrolling="no" class="testFrame" id="frame1"> </iframe>
```

AND here is Jquery snippet for src bind

```
<script>
var host = "https://sharecad.org/", frame = "cadframe/load?url=";
var urlBase = '@(instanceUrl+"/data/")';
var reloadIframe = function (frame, src) {
            frame.src = src ? src : host + "cadframe";
}
</script>
```

initially, I tried with the existing .dxf file which worked properly. But few of .dxf is not shown there,
to recheck I tried some online viewer like https://viewer.autodesk.com/ and https://www.3dvieweronline.com/ and there those generated file work there.

is there any restriction on file size by sharecad? 
is there any other viewer for that...

Comment: here is my CAD file [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1-a5K1vu5zXwUk8vD6xMocIILB6lbUmW3)

Comment: Their own website version of the viewer works.with your file.

Comment: with little changes in iframe url its working now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After discussion with sharecad support team, I come to know that the current url which I was using had some issue so they gave me new URL which is supporting it properly.
here is new iframe

```
<iframe src="beta.sharecad.org/cadframe/load?url=https://xyz/data/Demo.dxf" scrolling="no" class="testFrame" id="frame1"> </iframe>
```

Adding an answer as if anyone faces the same issue while using sharecad.org iframe

Answer (score 0):

https was not working for me, i have used the link with only http it was fine. Try it and let us know

Comment: I'm using beta url of it... its working for me